# How run in the background a Task with F# on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, f#, background-process

I'm triying to use a http server inside my android xamarin.forms app. It need to translate this C# code:

```
        var server = WebServer
            .Create(url)
            .EnableCors()
            .WithLocalSession()
            .WithStaticFolderAt("c:/web");

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = server.RunAsync(cts.Token);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
        cts.Cancel();

        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        } catch (AggregateException)
        {
            // We'd also actually verify the exception cause was that the task
            // was cancelled.
            server.Dispose();
        }
```

Now, the problem is that `task.Wait()` block and make the android App to be non responsive.

Now, I try to put the task into the form app:

```
type App() =
    inherit Application()

    let mutable task:System.Threading.Tasks.Task = null

    do
        let t, form = mainWebForm()
        task <- t
        base.MainPage <- form

        async {
          task.Start()
        } |> ignore
```

But it not work on Android. However, in iOS it work fine (ie: the web server start listening)

Comment: 1) What error (or what kind of unexpected behaviour) do you get? 2) How come that `task.Wait` call in C# was not a problem? Was the code block in some larger context you omitted?

Comment: 1) Not error. Just the web server not listen. 2) Because it was in a comman line app. In a xamarin.forms app it block the UI and the android OS try to kill the app (because look like the app hang)

Answer (score 0):

Creating an async and passing it to `ignore` does not actually run the code inside the async. It creates a computation that would do something when started, but never starts it. So, if you wanted to use `async`, your last three lines could be something like this:

```
async {
      task.Start()
} |> Async.Start
```

However, you also switched from calling `task.Wait()` to calling `task.Start()` which should independently also prevent blocking the thread. So you can most likely just call:

```
task.Start()
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do the blocking `Wait` inside an `async` queued in background, you would write (but note that there should be absolutely no reason for doing this):

```
async {
      task.Wait()
} |> Async.Start
```

Comment: Sorry, the ignore blind me to the fact the webserver already started the task. So I try to do the task.Wait() inside async and yet nothing happened. The weird thing is that is only on android. The same code on iOS work fine.

Comment: It might be worth trying to wrap the `task.Wait` call inside an exception handler and see if there is any exception - asynchronous exceptions might get ignored, so there might be some error you're missing.